# Aggregating a resultset in java

Tags: java, sql, database, optimization, resultset

I have a sales database table with the following data:

**Year**       **Month**    **Flowertype**    **Totalsales** 
  2014             1                    dandalion             100 
 2014             2                    dandalion             100 
 2014             2                    rose                    100 
 2014             3                    rose                    100 
2015             1                    dandalion             100 
2015             2                    dandalion             100

And i would like to add aggregations of the totalsales data based on the other columns, like this:

**Year**       **Month**    **Flowertype**    **Totalsales** 
  2014             1                    dandalion             100 
 2014             2                    dandalion             100 
 2014             2                    rose                    100 
 2014             3                    rose                    100 
2015             1                    dandalion             100 
2015             2                    dandalion             100

---

all                   1                    dandalion             200 
 all                 2                    dandalion             200 
all                 2                    rose                     200 
all                 3                    rose                     100 
 2014             all                   dandalion         200 
 2014             all                 rose                      200 
2015             all                   dandalion             200 
2014             1                    all                        100 
2014             2                    all                        200 
2014             3                    all                        100 
2015             1                    all                        100 
2015             2                    all 
                       100 

all                all                   dandalion            400 
all                all                   rose                    200 
2014             all                  all 
                       400 
2015             all                  all                        200 
all                1                    all                        200 
all                2                    all 
                       300 
all                3                    all 
                       100 
all              all                    all 
                       600

Can someone push me in the right direction on, after connecting to the database, how i should do that? I would like to do it in Java. I also would like to do it in an efficient way, because the real table contains many more columns/records.

To clarify: i would like to write a smart script that inserts the aggregated data. And i would like to hear some idea's on how that script should work. Thanks!

Comment: This question is extremely unspecific. Are you an absolute Java beginner? Or is it that you don't know how to connect to a database, retrieve data and update tables?

Comment: what you are asking is how to use things in SQL such as `GROUP BY` or `SUM`

Comment: Yes i do know how to connect to the database and insert/retrieve data, but i would like to know how to insert all those records with aggregated data in an efficient way. But thank you for your answer, i'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to create `views` for each of the particular aggregations and then just issue a simple `SELECT` on those. For instance:

```
all       1           dandalion       200
all       2           dandalion       200
all       2           rose            200
all       3           rose            100
```

could be

`SELECT 'all' as year, month, flowertype, sum(totalsales) from sales group by month, flowertype order by month`

and the next block

```
2014   all         dandalion       200
2014   all         rose            200
2015   all         dandalion       200
```

could be

`SELECT year, 'all' as month', flowertype, sum(totalsales) from sales group by year, flowertype order by year`

etc.

Comment: Okay thank you, but my real table contains a lot of combinations of columns/aggregated data that need to be inserted as blocks. What i would like to write is a Java-program that does this for me in an efficient way. Any idea's on how this program should insert the data?